# Spivak's Calculus chapter 1 problem 12 v

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value

I am having trouble proving $$|x|-|y|≤|x-y|.$$
In the solutions it says
$$|x|=|y-(y-x)|≤|y|+|y-x|, \quad \text{so} \quad |x|-|y|≤|x-y|.$$
Am I missing something here? How did he get $|x-y|$ on the right side?

Answer (score 2):

$|x|=|-x|$ where x is any real number.

so $|x-y|=|y-x|$

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand it perfectly now. :)!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|x|=|-x|$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$.

Hence, we have
$$|y-x|=|-(y-x)|=|x-y|.$$

So,  $|x|\le |y|+|y-x|$ and $|y-x|=|x-y|$ lead $$|x|-|y|\le|x-y|.$$

Answer (score 0):

we have used in your proof that  $|y-x|=|x-y|$